# supervisor: spawnerr: can't find command

Tags: debian, supervisord

I installed [supervisord](http://supervisord.org) using pipe. 
And created configuration file

```
[program:sleep]
command="/bin/sleep 1000"
```

But when I restart service I always see in log

```
INFO spawnerr: can't find command '/bin/sleep 1000'
```

Please, say what's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this problem. Just delete quotes.

```
[program:sleep]
command=/bin/sleep 1000
```

I recommend you read article [Daemon-ize your processes on the cheap, part two: Supervisor](http://ryanmckern.com/2013/01/daemon-ize-your-processes-on-the-cheap-part-two-supervisor/)

Comment: Do you know that you saved me a lot of time! Thank you so much :-)